# Data Extension shows 0 records after importing from Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, import

My Marketing Cloud connected to a Salesforce instance and I want to retrieve data from a report in Salesforce into a Data Extension. And that DE shows 0 records (even the report has 1 record) after importing from Salesforce. I don't know if I did in a wrong way.

At first, I went to Email Studio/Interactions/Import and created an import

[image]

And it also automatically created a DE (with fields in the report) in Salesforce Data Extension folder with 0 records.
My question is how I can retrieve those records from the report in order to keep my DE up to date?

P/s I tried to go to Automation studio and used an import activity, chose the import above and "run once" but nothing happened. The DE is still 0 records

[image]

Comment: Did you start the import that you created in Email Studio? There's a little green "play"-like button which you need to press to start selected imports. Also, make sure to put in your email address in the notifications section - that way you will get notified in case there's an error

Comment: @zuzannamj I really appreciate your help. I'm new with MC so I didn't notice to click the "start" button. I have another question. So in order to keep my DE up to date, can I make an automation like above and schedule it to run daily? Will it work?

Comment: Adding it as an answer in case someone has the same problem in the future :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pull the data from the report, you need to trigger the import by checking the box next to the interaction you created and clicking on the "start" button.

Here is the documentation:

> 1. MC > Email Studio > Email > Interactions > Import > Create > Name the import > File Location: Salesforce Objects & Reports > Salesforce
>    Data Source Type: Report (radio button) > Select > *search the name of
>    the report to be imported* > Find Now > Select the Report to be
>    imported > OK
> 2. You must select these fields (and configure correctly for this to work):
>
> - Contact ID/Lead ID/SF ID field > Select 'Key' checkbox
> - Email > Set 'Type' to: 'Email Address' > Uncheck 'Nullable' box
> - Select the fields you would like to be included in the import, remember to check the SF ID and email fields
>
> 3. Save Config
> 4. Finalize Import definition and enter 'Send notification email to' if you would like.
> 5. In the Imports list > Check the box next to the import > Start
> 6. A Data Extension will be created in the 'Salesforce Data Extensions' folder with the same name as the Import you just created.
> 7. Utilize the Salesforce Data Extension created as any normal DE for sends or segmentation.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316824&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Also, make sure to put in your email address in the notifications section - that way you will get notified in case there's an error.

To answer your second question - yes, the import can be automated by running it on a schedule in Automation Studio.